# Jquery knockout - define variables inside templates

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I have a knockout template, in which i want to define a local parameter (which is a result of a function), and use it inside the template.

```
<script type="text/html" id="suggestedEmail-template">
    {{ var customVariable = processResult($data); }}
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: emailValue, attr: { 'data-customValue': customVariable }"></span>
    </li>
</script>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
<script type="text/html" id="suggestedEmail-template">
    <!-- ko if: customVariable = processResult($data) -->
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: emailValue, attr: { 'data-customValue': customVariable }"></span>
    </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
</script>
```

Comment: Be careful when using such a variable in foreach binding, since it will be updated in each loop! So it depends a lot on when the variable is then used: I used it for passing a value in 'click' event but unfortunately the passed value became the same for each item...

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a [computed variable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html):

Inside your view model:

```
var self = this;
self.customVariable = ko.computed(function()
{
    return processResult(this);
};
```

Then in your html:

```
<span data-bind="text: emailValue, attr: { 'data-customValue': customVariable }"></span>
```

Comment: I think the idea was to execute the function for each templated item.  Using computed would be a single value.

Comment: Well, he only mentions one template and one custom variable in his question, so I was going on that!